# What's the best way to implement `quiet = TRUE` argument to a R function with cli messages?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to implement a `quiet` argument to a R function that has a lot of `cli` messages.

I would like something like `options(suppressMessages(classes = "cliMessage"))` (it doesn't work) to supress all cliMessage with just a line of code.

Something like this:

```
name <- function(variables, quiet = FALSE) {
  
  if(quiet == TRUE){
    
    options......
    
  }
  
  cli::cli_alert_info("example1")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example2")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example3")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example4")
}
```

One verbose way to create it is:

```
name <- function(variables, quiet = FALSE) {

  if(quiet == TRUE){

  cli::cli_alert_info("example1") %>%
    suppressMessages(classes = "cliMessage")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example2") %>%
    suppressMessages(classes = "cliMessage")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example3") %>%
    suppressMessages(classes = "cliMessage")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example4") %>%
    suppressMessages(classes = "cliMessage")

  }

  cli::cli_alert_info("example1")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example2")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example3")
  cli::cli_alert_info("example4")
}
```

But then I have to rewrite all my function twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options.

1. Tell your users to use `suppressMessages(name())` if they want to suppress messages. This also suppresses messages from downstream functions, and from `message()` as well.
2. Emit your messages conditionally:

   ```r
   if (!quiet) cli_alert_info("Up and running!")
   ```
3. Set the `cli.default_handler` option in your function and restore it in `on.exit()`:

   ```r
    name <- function(quiet = FALSE) {
      if (quiet) {
        old <- options(cli.default_handler = function(...) { })
        on.exit(options(old), add = TRUE)
      }
      cli::cli_alert_info("Up and running!")
    }
   ```

   This only suppresses messages from cli, but also from downstream
   functions, i.e. from functions called in `name`.